# I need help understanding the code for reversing a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse, swap

I need help understanding a function for reversing the array of string.

I have been looking through a few codes, and just trying to understand it. It is a function using a pointer.

```
void ReverseString(char *pStr){
    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(pStr[i]!='\0')
    {
        length++;
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        char temp = pStr[length - i - 1] ;
        pStr[length - i - 1] = pStr[i];
        pStr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

I am expecting it to reverse a string; I have a `main` function that uses it.

Comment: What parts do you understand?

Comment: If you really want to understand it you could use paper and pencil to "play computer" and step through the code, keeping track of variables and their values.

Comment: I am trying to understand why do we need the variable length.Also i did try to use paper and pen to get an idea, but i am not able to get the loop or the variable length

Comment: How would you swap e.g. first and last if you didn't know where the last one was?

Comment: The parameter `char *pStr` is just a pointer, it doesn't tell you how long the string is. The length must be computed in your function.

Comment: i would be creating another array to then put the last element of string first

Comment: It's more efficient here, at each position until the middle of the string, it swap the nth and the length-nth character. It only has to buffer one character instead of creating a temporary buffer the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are sequences of characters terminated with a zero character `'\0'`.

So this loop

```
while(pStr[i]!='\0')
{
    length++;
    i++;
}
```

calculates the length of the string that is how many characters there are in the string before the zero character. Instead of the loop you could use standard C function `strlen` declared in header `<string.h>`.

This loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
    char temp = pStr[length - i - 1] ;
    pStr[length - i - 1] = pStr[i];
    pStr[i] = temp;
}
```

swaps character from the first half of the string with characters of the second half of the string. That is the first character is swapped with the last character, the second character is swapped with the before last character and so on until the middle of the string.

The function has several drawbacks. It could be written (without using standard C functions) the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * ReverseString( char *pStr )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    // Calculates the number of characters in the string 
    // excluding the zero character.
    // SO the variable n will contain the number of characters in the string. 
    while ( pStr[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    // Swaps characters from the first half of the string with 
    // the characters of the second half of the string.
    // So the loop has only n / 2 iterations. 
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ ) 
    {
        char c = pStr[n - i - 1] ;
        pStr[n - i - 1] = pStr[i];
        pStr[i] = c;
    }

    return pStr;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "Prachi Rajesh Jansari";

    puts( s );
    puts( ReverseString( s ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Prachi Rajesh Jansari
irasnaJ hsejaR ihcarP
```

Comment: are you sure that this is not a duplicate though

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Maybe it is a duplicate question. I am just trying to answer any question.

Comment: Interesting, let's see how long you can do it :D